# failed to send the qLaunchSuccess packet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using XCode 4.3.2 and trying to open an already existing project based on the Facebook SDK sample Project for XCODE and run it on a target IPhone with IOS 4.2. 
Although it runs on the simulator it crashes on the IPhone printing this error on the console:

```
failed to send the qLaunchSuccess packet
```

I really do not know what could be the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [failed to send the qLaunchSuccess packet, can't debug in the device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834708/failed-to-send-the-qlaunchsuccess-packet-cant-debug-in-the-device)

Comment: it is actually the same problem but I have already looked at that question's answers and they do not apply or fix my issue

Comment: Then you have a privileges issue.  Restart your phone and try again.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Restart your phone.  You know that long list of privilege options in the build settings tab?  Those.  They break occasionally.

Comment: you got it! thank you it was driving me crazy, answer the question so that I can accept it

Comment: I'll put it up as the answer then.

Comment: You can also make a clean of your project

Comment: I get this all the time, really annoying, restart the iOS device is the only 'fix' I have found

Comment: Restart device and Xcode not help.
I found that I'm using distribution provision profile.
Hope this help. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might have some broken privileges or a hung debugger process (one that didn't quite exit fast enough).  Restart Xcode or restart your phone, either way, it's not as bad as it's more annoying cousin, `Processes That Can't Be Registered To The BootStrap Server`

If all else fails, restore it from a backup.

Comment: changed nothing for me unfortunately

Comment: Well it helped the OP.  the 3 downvotes were completely of of character.

Answer (score 22):

This happened to me when I accidentally tried to do a device debug using a distribution profile.  As soon as I noticed and switched it to a dev profile, the issue went away.

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 4.3.3, this is caused by re-running the app (command+R) or stopping it (command+.) while halted on a breakpoint. To fix the error once you've gotten it, it usually works to stop the app, (command+.), unplug the device, plug it back in, and run the app again.

To avoid the issue in the future, remember to continue (command+control+y or hit the play button near the debugger output) before stopping. If you have many breakpoints or are in a loop, you can deactivate one breakpoint by going to that line and hitting command + \ or you can deactivate all breakpoints by hitting command + y.

If you eventually get the error ending in "This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger," you need to reboot the device.

I submitted a bug report to Apple. I suggest you all do the same so that this gets the attention it deserves.

Edit: the "qLaunchSuccess packet" bug doesn't happen in Xcode 4.4 or 4.5 as it did in 4.3. However, 4.4 and 4.5 experience "Timed out waiting for app to launch" instead--possibly the same issue with a new message. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683308/xcode-4-4-error-timed-out-waiting-for-app-to-launch) question for some possible solutions. Nothing works for met yet. The behavior seems different than 4.3.3 because the error doesn't come up every time I stop while halted on a breakpoint. I will experiment and see if my workaround for 4.3 also fixes the 4.4/4.5 issue.

Answer (score 3):

I get this every time my app crashes, and I restart it by doing a Run.  If I hit the Stop button before doing a run then I don't get this.

After some time, if I keep hitting Run instead of Stop first, the iPhone will only show the above error message and the only solution is to restart the iPhone.  Quitting and restarting Xcode does not help.

This may be an Xcode bug.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly quicker way to resolve this issue without restarting the device is to change the language.

Settings - > General - > International (4th from bottom) - > Language (top)

Alternatively If you have a bugged News stand app (in a folder) just tap it to restart springboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I was trying to install over a bad version of the app that had been crashing on launch. Restarting Xcode and the device did not make the error go away, but deleting the app fixed the problem.