# xCode qlaunchsuccess Error

Tags: ios, xcode

some weeks from now I've been receiving this strange message almost every time I try tu run an app from XCode.

`error: failed to launch '//here's the route to my app//' -- failed to send the qLaunchSuccess packet`

I've been searching for information and I've found some answers about certificate issues. I've set the code signing to my developer, not distribution, certificate so it's not the same problem I think. 
The bad news are that each time this error happens for a while (2 -3 times in a row) the app gets freezed on the bootstrap server and there's no other way to fix it than resetting the device, which makes me lose a lot of time. 
Any solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10055109/1228534

Comment: I've already tried everything there but this error keeps appearing until the "bootstrap server" appears, then I have to restart my device and for a while it works OK but eventually it keeps failing with this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I tried everything on graver's post with no result, tried reinstalling XCode and resetting the device with no results.
I've submitted a bug report to Apple, #11740012. I hope it'll be answered, as this error is annoying the hell out of me, having to force reset the device each hour or two hours, and receiving this error many times an hour is a pain in the *!$!

**UPDATED :Problem isn't solved for XCode 4.3, but upgrading to XCode 4.4 have solved the issue, so I recommend to upgrade to everyone with this problem**