# XCode 4.4 error on launching app on iOS Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4.4 error - Timed out waiting for app to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683308/xcode-4-4-error-timed-out-waiting-for-app-to-launch)

I have been programming an app and testing on simulator for a while. But recently I tried to test it on my iOS device (iPhone 4, 5.1.1)

To make it run without a developer's account, I had to edit the SDK properly list (changed code signing require to NO, and entitlement required to NO)
Then i changed the Code Signing Identity to "Don't Code Sign". All was good till here.

When I tried to run it on the iOS device, I saw my app icon on my iPhone, but an error occurred on XCode saying, "timed out waiting for app to launch" and I noticed an animation as the application is being popping up but actually nothing opens up.

To see if theres anything wrong with my code/project, I created a new project and tried to run that on iOS device, I saw a new app's icon with the same problem.

Everything works perfect on Simulator.

Can anybody tell me what is this issue? And how can I fix it?

P.S. I tried restarting my iPhone and XCode. But same result. And it's on debug configuration already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a developer account to build to the device. Changing code signing settings in Xcode doesn't change anything; iOS will still require binaries be signed with an Apple-issued developer certificate.

Comment: ... unless you jail-break your phone. But yes, get the developer subscription.

Comment: I have my iPhone jailbroken. How do I make it work on it?