# Timed out waiting for app to launch

Tags: xcode, build

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4.4 error - Timed out waiting for app to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683308/xcode-4-4-error-timed-out-waiting-for-app-to-launch)

I am building an app in Release, and running on an iPhone 4s.

When I click on run, everything works well, my application even runs on the iPhone.

But one or two seconds later, I have an error from Xcode : "Timed out waiting for app to launch" while my app is still running.

It is pretty weird and I would like to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Are you loading too many things in the AppDelegate? Be careful with this, because when you submit an App to the AppStore, if the app spends too much time launching they will reject your app.
Check this link [Timed out waiting for app to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683308/xcode-4-4-error-timed-out-waiting-for-app-to-launch)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am doing only one thing in my AppDelegate, I initiate a push notification SDK of my company, a lot of our other applications do the same stuff and there are no problems. In fact my application is running since at least 5 or 6 seconds when the message appears.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking too long to start up before indicating your app is loaded.  Either do you start up code asynchronously, or embed a call to:

```
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Before you start your long operation.

Comment: I call this before loading anything.