# Xcode says it cannot launch app when it in fact does run

Tags: iphone, xcode, timeout, device

What do I do about this?

Xcode launches the app on the device and it starts up, but when it has started the image below pops up and when I click "OK" it crashes the app.

The simulator has no issues, but I cannot read the console in regards to debugging because of this. There really is not a reason why this should be happening.

Also I have no idea what code could cause this. I have no errors or warnings and everything has been fine right up until yesterday.
If there is any code or more info you need to help me with this, please ask:-)

I have removed the app, restarted the devices and my mac.

[image]

Comment: Usually when this happens, you just need to completely power down your iPhone and restart it.

Comment: I tried that and just again when you mentioned it and no luck - also this happens on 2 devices

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer here:

[Same issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683308/xcode-4-4-error-timed-out-waiting-for-app-to-launch)

Basically you can't do debugging on a Ad-Hoc profile:-)

Comment: Note that you probably can read the console of the running app, from the "Organizer".