# Xcode5 Timeout Trying to launch App

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to run an app on my device, but I keep getting the timeout errors. I've tried everything else that is suggested. I've

- Ensured the Provisioning profile is not an Ad Hoc or Distribution one
- Cleaned many times
- Reset Xcode just about every time
- Deleted the app countless times
- Cleaned provisioning profiles out from device.

But still nothing. If I set the Scheme to "Wait for Launch", I'm able to get the app to run.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is there in earlier Xcode versions as well.

Check this: [Timed out waiting for app to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683308/xcode-4-4-error-timed-out-waiting-for-app-to-launch)