# Push Notification Development to Distribution Certificate issue iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, xcode4.3, distribution

i have changed the **Development certificates to Distribution certificate**.

But getting below  error while launching from xcode.

```
error: failed to launch '/Users/labuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-apnhncqwnlqivrhbmcomabillpjh/Build/Products/appname-iphoneos/appname.app/appname' -- failed to send the qLaunchSuccess packet
```

The application not able to launch from xcode. but installed  in iphone. then i am able to access installed apps.

any one know about reason for this issue.

Comment: already have several resources at stackoverflow. for example, follow the links # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055109/failed-to-send-the-qlaunchsuccess-packet and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834708/failed-to-send-the-qlaunchsuccess-packet-cant-debug-in-the-device. at first please search, then post your question. It is much important to make Stack Over Flow # SPAM free

Comment: @MahbuburRAaman               thank you for your response..             i referred many url.. but did not get accurate result. thats y posted a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happened to me, when I accidentally tried to do a device debug using a distribution profile.But while  switched to a dev profile, the issue went away.

**you cannot debug using distribution profile.**